# How does Git indicate that a file is a symlink?

Tags: git

I'm writing a utility that needs to be able to detect programatically that a particular blob in a Git tree is a symlink.

Let's say I create a symlink in a Git repo:

```
> echo target > target
> ln -s target link
> git add target link
> git commit -m "Add target and link"
```

How can I tell from within Git that the file **link** is a symlink?  "git show" just shows the path of the target:

```
> git show HEAD:link
target
```

I can use git ls-tree, but it's very clunky:

```
> git ls-tree HEAD:
120000 blob 1de565933b05f74c75ff9a6520af5f9f8a5a2f1d    link
100644 blob eb5a316cbd195d26e3f768c7dd8e1b47299e17f8    target
```

Here, the mode 120000 indicates a symlink.  However, surely there must be a more elegant way of detecting in Git that a file is a symlink?

Comment: I think that's about all you can do except create a `git is-symlink` wrapper around it or something

Comment: Do you have to do this with a `git` command? How does checking the status of the file itself (`if [ -h link ] ; then ... ; fi`) not meet your requirements?

Comment: @KeithThompson I want to be able to check the status without doing a git reset.